# pageProps vs props in nextjs

Tags: redux, next.js, react-props, next-redux-wrapper

I looked at what *nextjs* returns when navigating the page and noticed that the state of hydration is duplicated on the page and transmitted in two different properties of the object:
[image]
I do not understand whether this is the norm of logic or whether it is not a duplication of logic.

I use `next-i18next` for multilingualism and `next-redux-wrapper` for hydration of `redux` storage on the server, and this is exactly the state it creates and is located in these two properties.

Therefore, when I noticed this, I wondered if this was normal logic, since my storage is not so small, and I would not like any extra operations when working on the server.

If you need more information, write in the comments.

Comment: Do you have a Custom App Component at  `./pages/_app.js`? And whether the pageProps and props have exactly the same values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the two set of props- `pageProps` and `props` are related to the loading of the Custom App component and the page component respectively. You can read about Custom App component [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app)

And as the doc states.

> pageProps is an object with the initial props that were preloaded for
> your page by one of our data fetching methods, otherwise it's an empty
> object.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and I have a custom _app.jsx, but I'm still wondering if it's correct that the data is repeated and I should just accept it as a given?

Comment: From my understanding of the docs linked in the answer, the data is not repeated. The `pageProps` represents all the props that is passed to the page from a data fetching method like [getServersideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) before the page is hydrated. And `props` represents all props passed to the component including those passed from parent components which includes its immediate parent and even the Custom App component. Does that make sense?

Comment: So, I understand correctly, `props` in response to this code https://i.imgur.com/zkn827h.png ?